# How to use a class from one JS file in another JS file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use a class from **A.js** file in **B.js** file,
i made an instance of **A.js** class and tried to call its function in **B.js**, but i got an error 
saying

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

this is what the code looks like:

*A.js file*

```
export class A {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'A'
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

*B.js file*

```
import A from './A.js';
const a = new A();
console.log(a.getName());
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you are not evaluating the code as module. How are you executing the code?

Comment: <script src="B.js"></script> in google chrome browser

Answer (score 1):

In your file ***B.js***, change the import from `import A from './A.js';` to `import { A } from './A.js';`

There are two ways to *export* a class or a function:

1) *default*

2) *named*

1) allows a single export per file. The naming of import is independent of the original exported name.

**Example:**

```
export default class A { } // A.js
import AComponent from './A';
```

2) allows multiple exports per file. The name of the import has to be the same as the name of the export.

**Example:**

```
export class A { } // A.js
import { A } from './A';
```

Comment: While that's correct, the OP's current problem is that they are not loading the code as a module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `keyword` `default` if you are using import without `{}`. try a code like below -

```
export default class A {
    constructor() {
        this.name = 'A'
    }
    getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Or you can use alias like this -

```
import * as A from './A.js';
```

Comment: While that's correct, the OP's current problem is that they are not loading the code as a module. *"Or you can use alias like this"* Then they would have to access the class with `A.A` though...